# Why sitefinity list allows wrong page url or allows paging?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am using sitefinity 10.1 MVC. When I used sitifinity list on my page then it allow my page to go to wrong URL. For example, my page link is **www.example.com** and when I try **www.example.com/12**, instead of taking me to 404 error page it allows this URL and lands on the actual page. I need to take **www.example.com/12** to 404 page.

Comment: so it lands on page 12 of your listing data?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev The URL *www.example.com/12* lands on this URL *www.example.com*. Currently, I am getting all list items on my first hit. So when I hit "www.example.com/1" it displays all list items but when I hit "www.example.com/x" (x--> other than 1) it displays none of the list items.

Comment: hm, I do not completely understand. First you say when you go to /12 it *redirects* to /, but then you say when you go to /x it displays none of the list items. Which one is it? Can you explain in a bit more details?

Comment: I mean when I go to "www.example.com/x" (x--> other than 1) it lands on the same page which is  "www.example.com" but it does not display any of the list item. I just need to move this URL "www.example.com/x" to 404 page

Comment: I am using *sitefinity MVC* type List control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the "Enable Parameter Validation" setting is checked (by default).

When it is checked, Sitefinity leaves the widgets on the page to determine whether they can handle this page or should return 404.

Until a widget says "no, I can't and should not handle this page", a normal page is returned. The List widget is not one that would complain in this case.

It overrides the HandleUnknownAction where it simply invokes the Index action of the controller and says "I am good with this page, you do what you want with it".

So what you can try is going to Title and Properties of the page and scroll down, expand the Advanced options and uncheck **Enable Parameter Validation**. Save and try again.